# OpenGL confused order of push and pop

Tags: c++, opengl

i am trying to get my opengl app working , basically before i started messing with a scene graph , every object started the draw with a push and then ended with a pop

now i am adding basically two children to a base of a car (the wheels) and i am having problems getting them to draw in relation to the base car if i am able to post some code i will show the calls to draw everything and then show my scenegraph call to draw and im hoping its a silly mistake as atm im honestly stuck

```
void GameNode::Draw()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();
car->Draw();
glPopMatrix();

for (int i = 0; i < MAXOBJECTS; i++)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    objects[i]->Draw();
    glPopMatrix();
}

for (int i = 0; i < MAXBUILDINGS; i++)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    build[i]->Draw();
    glPopMatrix();
}

glPushMatrix();
skyBox->Draw();
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
 }
```

then in my car->draw i have the scene graph here is the code to that

```
glPushMatrix();


object->Draw();
glPushMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
if(left != nullptr)
    {

        glPushMatrix();

        glPopMatrix();

        left->PreOrderDraw();
    }
if(right != nullptr)
{
    right->PreOrderDraw();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

so this basically sets my wheels near the base of car but isnt setting them relative to the base when their positions are a offset to where they should be

Comment: I feel obliged to warn anyone I see using outdated opengl that the  martix stack and features such as glBegin are deprecated and no longer used.

Comment: I feel oblidged to note that altough that stuff is deprecated since several years, it is unfortunately still widely in use... ;)

Comment: Yeah, just letting them know in case they didn't actually know. I didn't for a while.

Comment: What happens inside PreOrderDraw()?  It seems there is an excessive number of Push/Pops, but from a quick look they all look aligned properly.  My guess is object->Draw() will push, setup the matrix, draw, then pop the matrix, which is possibly why the wheels are not located relative to the car?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting confused on how the matrix stack works. I say this due to issues such as:

```
glPushMatrix( );
glPopMatrix( );

if(left != nullptr)
{

    glPushMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();

   // ...
```

You are pushing/popping multiple times for no reason (unless there is omitted code).

I suggest that you read [OpenGL Programming Guide - Chapter 3 - Manipulating the Matrix Stacks](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name6) which, fortunately for you, uses a car and it's wheels as the example for teaching how to use the stack.

From what I can tell from your code, all you are doing is pushing/popping the identity matrix multiple times without ever translating the wheels from their origin.

Comment: hi thanks for that link since posting this i have realised just what the push and pop do , so i managed to get the one wheel to be relative to the car and from what i can see the second wheel is going relative to the first wheel so i must be missing a push somewhere thanks i will read all that and look at what im doing wrong

Comment: If the second wheel is behaving relative to the first, then you actually missed a `glPopMatrix` it seems

Comment: ye thanks i found it it all works properly now thanks :D